# how I access to facebook album with as3?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-as3-api

I am newbie to faceook with as3. how I started ? tutorial ? I purpose accessing to facebook album ? What should be my My first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [AS3 Facebook API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) to start.

There are a few tutorials and samples on [Adobe's website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/samples.html#2).

Comment: We should really start a page with answers to all the most common Facebook + AS3 questions...